# svg element position while scrolling in WKWebView

Tags: ios, d3.js, svg, wkwebview

In a document rendered in WKWebView for iOS, part of d3.js based svg elements are positioned in the event listener of `window` for `scroll` event to pin to the left of the visible area of document.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
     d3selection.attr("transform", "translate(" + window.scrollX + ", 0)"); // d3selection is a d3.js selection
});
```

This method almost worked except that the element which was intended to stay still wobbled during scrolling. How to make this svg element stay still?

Comment: put the pinned drawing in a separate absolutely positioned container perhaps?

Comment: @RobertLongson it works, thanks.

Comment: @RobertLongson Weird things happened. On desktop browser it all goes fine. But in simulator/iOS, the fixed element is scrolling half the speed of the screen.